# SonarLint (IntelliJ Idea) failing to update binding: Minimum required version error

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

I haven't been able to update SonarLint's rules from the organization's SonarQube Server for a while now.
It was working perfectly, but suddenly I started to get the following message:
[image: Update binding error: wrong version]

I'm guessing that maybe the SonarQube server was updated to a newer version (currently it is Version 5.6), but how do I upgrade my local plugin version to match it? (if that was what this error means).
I waited for the plugin to release another update (v2.9) and hoped that would do the trick, but it didn't, same result.

I found this page, where it says that for SonarQube 5.6+, I should be using the most recent SonarJava 4.7.1 plugin, but don't know how to say my SonarLint plugin (version 2.9.0.1816) to use that.
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarJava

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Current environment:
SonarQube Server: 5.6 
IntelliJ Idea: 2017.1
IntelliJ SonarLint: 2.9.0.1816

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the SonarLint *Connected Mode*, so the code analyzers (SonarQube Plugins) used are the ones installed on the SonarQube server. The error message here means that, **on the SonarQube server**, you must upgrade [SonarJava](https://www.sonarsource.com/why-us/products/codeanalyzers/sonarjava.html) to at least v4.0, and a better choice would actually be the [latest version](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarJava) altogether.

Comment: Update on the server! Missed that completely! (slap) To be fair, the message is not that clear, not when you have plugins on the client and the server, and the error message was shown on the client :P Thanks Nicolas!